# Network distruption when scanning with amass or nmap

Tags: networking, router, dns, nmap, scanning

When I'm scanning with `amass` with `amass enum -active -brute -d {domain}` the average queries performed are `151/sec` and my connection gets disrupted at the point that it's not usable on any device connected to the network (I cannot even access to the router's page). Similar things happens when using `nmap` with `nmap -sV -v -A -sC {domain}`. This behaviour was very noticeable when scanning with `nessus` (which could be compared to nmap to some extent) with the *default settings*.

I believe the problem is the router(it's a propietary isp router manufactured by huawei called *vodafone station revolution*), should changing it solve the problem or it's someting else that it's causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the problem relies in the router itself as it does not have enough processing power to handle all the packets correctly.